# AIR Native extensions Hello World Example for iphone ios

Tags: objective-c

I need help as i am having runnable code library for Hello world which i took from the url,

> "http://akabana.info/2011/08/11/air-native-extension-10-try-air-for-ios-ane/"

in which we are making static library in *Xcode* by using **`ADOBE AIR.framework`** so that we are getting **`.a`** extension file. Now how to call further function because its just a library now how i want to know the steps further. How to call this library in the IOS project.

Answer (score 0):

Chck out this step by step tutorial
http://www.liquid-photo.com/2011/10/28/native-extension-for-adobe-air-and-ios-101/

Comment: can u please give me some guidance about this question....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15780349/call-normal-function-of-objective-c-from-freobject-function-to-native-air-applic